# CSS selector overriding

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to merge two CSS files from different vendors. The first one defines

```
body.mine div {border:1px solid red}
```

The second one

```
.blue-border {border:1px solid blue}
```

In the generated HTML, you can find

```
<div class="blue-border">hello</div>
```

This looks red, not blue. I can't modify the HTML, nor the first CSS code. My only "hope" is to modify the second CSS. Any hints? Thank you very much!

Example:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
     body.mine div {border:1px solid red}
     .blue-border {border:1px solid blue}
   </style>
 </head>
 <body class="mine">
   <div>hallo</div>
   <div class="blue-border">hello</div> <- looks red, not blue as I want
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this article [‘Shoot to kill; CSS selector intent’](http://csswizardry.com/2012/07/shoot-to-kill-css-selector-intent/)

Comment: @user1394965: This has nothing to do with CSS3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just make the selector more specific:

```
body.mine div.blue-border {border:1px solid blue}
```

This tells the browser to look for a much more specific element: A div with a class of blue-border that is a child of a body element that has a class of mine.

Yours just said "select anything that has a class of blue-border" and this was way less specific than the previous selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/tcWK5/

Comment: This is the right answer. CSS hacking like this is always fun! :)

Comment: The right answer? my answer was exactly the same and posted before, just doesn't have the jsfiddle so it's not wrong

Answer (score 4):

You just need a selector more specific than `body.mine` div, so that it overrides the less specific selector. Try something like:

```
body.mine div.blue-border {border:1px solid blue}
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also be a perfect use case for `!important`.

```
.blue-border {border:1px solid blue !important}
```

I realise that the use of `!important` is often frowned upon, but `.blue-border` is obviously a utility class that only does one thing, which means that the class shouldn't be used if the intented result is a red border.

In this instance I would prefer `!important` over the use of an over qualified selector, because over qualified selectors could have a major performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to change any property in all elements with css, do NOT define this property in specific elements:

```
html body div#very .specific { 
  /*  Any prop that is NOT the ones you want to apply generally  */ 

   margin: ...
   font-weight: ...

  /* NOT color, nor background, etc */
}


/* These now will catch in the above too */
.blue{ 
   color: blue;     
}
.back-yellow{   
   background: #ff0;
}
```

Explanation: the color and background will apply on all elements that don't have a more specific definition of color/background.

So, only define color in specific CSS path if you want to override the general rules.